# make a regex to find string containg a software name with its version number

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a text file that contains some description about various software components.
Now many of the software components are mentioned along with their version for example say I have a String in my file

```
"Stack Careers 2.0 is the new number 1 site with symbol ! and * and blablabla   
 replacing older Stack Careers."
```

Also it has some symbols and numbers as well.

I have done the splitting of the string with any character other than A-Za-z , below is the code for it.

```
getMySoftwareDescription().split("[^a-zA-Z]");
```

This gives me all the words(I actually want all the words and not any symbol or numbers other than the one that are software version numbers) like

`Stack,Careers,is,the`,etc. inside an array.

But I want to get the string `Stack Careers 2.0` as single string and also `Stack Careers`

(along with other words like `is`,`the` as it is )from the above example.

I would like to mention that I am not good at regex.

Comment: A regular expression can only match specific sequences of characters. It sounds like you're wanting to match and extract data based upon meaning. In which case you probably need to look into some form of Natural Language Processing...

Comment: I agree with Charlie. It will be very hard to distinguish between "Stack Careers 2.0" and ..was "buried under 2.0" tons of manure... and it sure can't be done generally with a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with this

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\p{Lu}[\\p{L} ]+)(\\d+[\\.]?\\d+)*|[\\S&&[^.]]+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Stack Careers 2.0 is the new number 1 site with symbol ! and \n* and blablabla\n replacing older Stack Careers.");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    while (m.find()) {
        list.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println(list);
```

output

```
[Stack Careers 2.0, is, the, new, number, 1, site, with, symbol, !, and, *, and, blablabla, replacing, older, Stack Careers]
```

Though it should be improved to recognize all possible options.

Comment: but i also want other words like "is" "the" "number" etc.